# How to use sourceSets to replace/override app icon in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'd like to use different icon in different flavor.

There's a default icon in my main sourceSets (in dir `src/main/res/mipmap-*dpi`), and I try to replace/override icon in build.gradle with sourceSets.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
    }
    debug {
        ...
    }
}

flavorDimensions "d1", "d2"
dimension11 {
    dimension "d1"
}

dimension21 {
    dimension "d2"
    sourceSets.debug {
        resources {
            srcDir 'config/icon/free' // my icon is in free/res/mipmap-*dpi
            exclude 'src/main/res/mipmap-*dpi' //not working, mipmap-*dpi and mipmap-*dpi-v4 are all in the final apk file.
        }
    }
}
dimension22 {
    dimension "d2"
}
dimension23 {
    dimension "d2"
}
```

It's not working, `mipmap-*dpi` and `mipmap-*dpi-v4` are all in the final apk file. `mipmap-*dpi-v4` are generated by agp.
If I rename `mipmap-*dpi` which in dir `config/icon/free` to `mipmap-*dpi-v4`, then:

> Entry name 'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png' collided

If I remove files which are in `src/main/res/mipmap-*dpi`,

> AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka mypackage:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

So how can I replace or override app icon? Can I achieve that with custom sourceSets?

TASK: installDimension11Dimension21Debug 
GRADLE: 6.8.3 
AGP: 4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use different app icons for different flavors, you need to create directory under **src** dir on the name of flavor. Add mimap folders under that dir with app icons.

[image]